# Selenium : Accept cookies which are located in an iframe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I tried to accept cookie which are located in an iframe. But none of what i tried work. I'm open to advice and correct way of doing it

Here is a screenshot of waht the site looks like :

[image: Screenshot]

Here is what my current code looks like :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import datetime
import re


def scrap_ouestfrance_immo(driver):

    URL = 'https://immobilier.lefigaro.fr/annonces/annonce-50413740.html'

    driver.get(URL)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 6)

    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@style='border: 0px none; min-width: 100%; position: fixed; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 100%; max-height: 100%; z-index: 2147483647']'")))

    accept_all_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="sc-1epc5np-0 dnGUzk sc-f7uhhq-2 coEmEP button button--filled button__acceptAll"]')
    accept_all_button.click()

    driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
    print('accepted cookies')



   
#Main 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    #opening browser
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # required when running as root user. otherwise you would get no sandbox errors.

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        # driver_path='/home/dev/chromedriver', 
        options=chrome_options,
        service_args=[
            '--verbose', 
            # '--log-path=/tmp/chromedriver.log'
        ]
    )

    scrap_ouestfrance_immo(driver)

    #driver.quit()
```

I tried to use Xpath, CSS Selector to switch to the iframe but i can't manage to do it.
The iframe doesn't have specific class o Id. I only see the style to switch to it.
But i maybe miss something

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression you have used to locate and switch to the iframe is incorrect. Try the below XPath expression instead:

```
(//iframe)[2]
```

Code should look like below:

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "(//iframe)[2]")))
```

**XPath expression explanation:** Basically this XPath will find the second iframe in the DOM structure.

Also change the code which locates Accept All button to below:

```
accept_all_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),"TOUT ACCEPTER")]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `xpath` to identify the `iframe` element and following css selector to cookie button.

After switching the frame wait for `element_to_be_clickable()`

```
driver.get("https://immobilier.lefigaro.fr/annonces/annonce-50413740.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='appconsent']/iframe")))
accept_all_button =wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.button--filled.button__acceptAll')))
accept_all_button.click()
```

Comment: Thank's @Kunduk ! It's workd like a charm and i find where was my error , have a nice day